# Authorization key issue: Swagger-ui v3.0.2

Tags: swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

i am using [Swagger-ui version 3.0.2](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui), i have hosted it locally and provided it my Json file and API it opens the document fine and lists all the method in the json file, after i put basic authentication in it, i did changes in the .JSON  file changes are

```
"securityDefinitions": {
"basic": {
        "type": "basic",
        "description": "Basic Authentication"
    },
    "token": {
        "type": "apiKey",
        "description": "API Token Authentication",
        "name": "apiKey",
        "in": "header"
    }
},
```

when i authencate a user with username and password or with toen it shows like it is authentacated but did not attach authentication key with the **CURL** [image: Swagger-ui 3.0.2]
here is the attachment where header is missing from the call.
for reference swagger-ui2.2.8 version screenshot.[image]

Can anyone guide how to attach authorization in header in swagger-ui 3.0.2 version.

Comment: Can you post your Swagger file (.json/.yaml)?

Comment: Do you use the `security` keyword, either for operations or on the root level? `securityDefinitions` defines possible security schemes, `security` actually attaches these schemes to operations.